#  Live USB not saving setting to not suspend when laptop lid is closed

Tags: power-management, live-cd, live-usb

I see that a [similar question exists](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17081/system-doesnt-respect-when-laptop-lid-is-closed-setting) but it's with regards to Ubuntu 10.10. I currently have Ubuntu 11.10. Also, I am unsure as to whether or not the Live booting would have anything to do with this issue.

I have tried going to the "Power" dialog and setting the close lid action to "Do Nothing" (as oppose to "Suspend). I then close the dialog, close the lid and still Ubuntu goes into suspended mode.

Although it seemed unlikely being that it's a Live boot, just in case, I tried rebooting after making the setting change but it still was suspending when the lid was closed.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your post to (1) add a link to the similar question, even though you are saying that your question may not be a duplicate, (2) specify what version of Ubuntu you are using, and (3) specify whether or not you are rebooting between when you change the setting and when you close the lid (if you are rebooting, then the setting will be lost, and you'll need to use a persistent live system or a customized one to keep it).

Comment: It had the version on the title. Jorge modified it. I will do the other edits. Thank you Eliah!

Comment: Jorge removed the version information from the title, but it does still belong in the body of the question. Also, "Ubuntu 11" is not a version of Ubuntu. This is ambiguous and could refer either to 11.04 or 11.10. (Similarly, "Ubuntu 10" could mean 10.04 LTS or 10.10.) It may help for us to know *specifically* what version you are using.

Comment: Ahhh okay. Sorry, new to Ubuntu. Did not know that the minor version had so much significance. Thank you!

Comment: Unlike with some software, it's not major.minor. The number before the `.` is the year in which is was scheduled for initial stable release, and the number after the `.` is the month. There may be as much or more (or less) change between successive releases with the same first number as between successive releases with different first numbers.

Comment: You said, "*Just in case, I tried rebooting after making the setting change but still suspending.*" I recommend editing your question again to clarify that you also tried *not* rebooting after making the change (since rebooting a live CD system reverts all changes). Assuming you did try that...

Comment: Thank you for the informative version information! Good to know. With regards to the 2nd comment, this part states that I tried without rebooting: `I have tried closing the lid directly after changing the setting to "Do Nothing" and it still suspended.` I will edit to make it more clear. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Live booting does not save the Power setting even in the same session. Once I actually installed Ubuntu on the my PC, the setting was being saved.